# How to catch ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED thrown by browser if server goes down in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, connection-refused

How to handle errors on the client-side if connection refuses by the server or the server is not up
[image: 1]

Comment: why you use `await` on `setInterval`

Comment: Please add code as text to the question rather than as an image.